# Should this be a SUMIF formula?

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I'm trying to make a formula that can recognize in Column A the name `Brooke B` for instance here, from there I'd like to SUM the values listed in Column I `Cash Discounts` for that specific user.

(Yes this user has no Cash Discounts, thus column I states "Non-Cash Payment").

There's about 80 users total here, so I'd prefer to automate the name recognition in Column A.
Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xzzHT7VjG24UJ4ZXaiZWsfzroTpn7jCJLexuTOf6SQs/edit?usp=sharing

Desired Results listed in `Cash Discounts` sheet, listed per user in column C.
[image]

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet and include an example of a successful outcome. For example, where to you expect that this formula would appear?

Comment: @Tedinoz I've updated my original question.

Comment: My apologies, Column L is in use with my ARRAYFORMULA in Cell D3, I updated my original question to specify Column C.

Comment: How does one identify the range start and end for each "person"? Column A contains the name as well as the date/time of the relevant transaction. Perhaps there a separate list of names? Looking at "Discounts", "Brook B" is an uncomplicated range; if one looks at, say, "Amber", there are several sub-headings and totals: "10% BuildingDiscount", "Northwestern 10%", "Streeter 10%" and each appears in column A, along with "Amber" and "Amber Total:". The layout of the spreadsheet doesn't lend itself to isolating discrete data elements. Question: is there scope to modify the spreadsheet design?

Comment: Unfortunately it’s a report from our Point Of Sale software, I’m unable to modify the output.

I removed the 10% listings from another formula using this
```=filter(Discounts!A1:A, regexmatch(Discounts!A1:A, " Total:"),NOT(REGEXMATCH(Discounts!A1:A,"10%")))```

Comment: "it’s a report from our Point Of Sale software". Oh... but there are some consistent elements (e.g. date/time is right aligned, always end in PM or AM) that might be used to reformat. How often do you need to do this analysis?

Comment: I have to do it on about 20 separate stores, preferably something I can easily just enter the report to and it will automatically calculate the rest. I will check to see if there is a more clear report for user names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to calculate the total amount of the Cash Discount per person given to people in a list. You have data that has been exported from a POS system to which that you have added a formula to calculate the amout of the discount on a line by line basis. You have speculated whether the discount totals could be calculated using `SUMIFS` formulae.

In my view, the layout of the spreadsheet and the format of the POS report do not lend themselves to isolating discrete data elements though Google sheets functions (though, no doubt, someone with greater skills than I will disprove this theory). Column A, containing names, also includes sub-groupings (and their sub-totals) as well as transaction dates. There are 83 unique persons and over 31,900 transaction lines.

This answer is a script-based solution which updates a sheet with the names and values of the discount totals. The elapsed execution time is @11 seconds.

---

```
function so5882893202() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get the Discounts sheet
  var discsheetname = "Discounts";
  var disc = ss.getSheetByName(discsheetname);

  //get the Discounts data
  var discStartrow = 3;
  var discLR = disc.getLastRow();
  var discRange = disc.getRange(discStartrow, 1, discLR-discStartrow+1, 9);
  var discValues = discRange.getValues();

  // isolate Column A
  var discnameCol = discValues.map(function(e){return e[0];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
  //Logger.log(discnameCol); // DEBUG

  // isolate Column I
  var discDiscounts = discValues.map(function(e){return e[8];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
  //Logger.log(discDiscounts); // DEBUG

  // create an array to build a names list
  var names =[]

  // get the number of rows on the Discounts sheet
  var discNumrows = discLR-discStartrow+1;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: number of rows = "+discNumrows);

  // identify search terms
  var searchPercent = "%";
  var searchTotal = "Total";

  // loop through Column A
  for (var i=0; i<discNumrows; i++){
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", content = "+discnameCol[i]);

    // test if value is a date
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(discnameCol[i]) != "[object Date]") {
       //Logger.log("it isn't a date") 

      // test whether the value contains a % sign
      if ( discnameCol[i].indexOf(searchPercent) === -1){
        //Logger.log("it doesn't have a % character in the content");

        // test whether the value contains the word Total
        if ( discnameCol[i].indexOf(searchTotal) === -1){
          //Logger.log("it doesn't have the word total in the content");

          // test whether the value is a blank
          if (discnameCol[i] != ""){
            //Logger.log("it isn't empty");

            // this is a name; add it to the list
            names.push(discnameCol[i])

          }// end test for empty

        }// end test for Total

      } // end for percentage

     }  // end test for date

  }// end for

  //Logger.log(names);

  // get the number of names
  var numnames = names.length;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: number of names = "+numnames)

  // create an array for the discount details
  var discounts=[];

  // loop through the names
  for (var i=0;i<numnames;i++){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: name = "+names[i]);

    // get the first row and last rows for this name 
    var startrow = discnameCol.indexOf(names[i]);
    var endrow = discnameCol.lastIndexOf(names[i]+" Total:");
    var x = 0;
    var value = 0;
    // Logger.log("name = "+names[i]+", start row ="+ startrow+", end row = "+endrow);

    // loop through the Cash Discounts Column (Column I) for this name 
    // from the start row to the end row
    for (var r = startrow; r<endrow;r++){ 

      // get the vaue of the cell
      value = discDiscounts[r];

      // test that it is a value
      if (!isNaN(value)){

        // increment x by the value
        x = +x+value;
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: r = "+r+", value = "+value+", x = "+x);
      }

    }
    // push the name and the total discount onto the array
    discounts.push([names[i],x]);

  }

  //Logger.log(discounts)

  // get the reporting sheet
  var reportsheet = "Sheet10";
  var report = ss.getSheetByName(reportsheet);

  // define the range (allow row 1 for headers)
  var reportRange = report.getRange(2,1,numnames,2);

  // clear any existing content
  reportRange.clearContent();

  //update the values
  reportRange.setValues(discounts);


}
```

---

**Report Sheet - extract**

[image: Report Sheet extract]

Answer (score 0):

Not everyone wants a script solution to their problem. This answer seeks to supply a *repeatable* solution using common garden-variety formula/functions.

As noted elsewhere, the layout of the spreadsheet does not lend itself to a quick/simple solution, but it IS possible to break down the data to compile a non-script answer. Though it may "seem" as though the following formula are less than "simple, when taken one-at-a-time they are logical, very easy to create, and very easy to verify successful outcomes.

Note: It is important to know at the outset that the first row of data = row#3, and the last row of data = row#31916.

**Step#1 - get `Text` values from ColumnA**

- Enter this formula in Cell J3, and copy to row 31916

  - `=if(isdate(A3),"",A3)`:
  - evaluates Column A, if the content is a date, returns blank, otherwise, returns the context
- Taking Customer "AJ" as an example, the content at this point includes:

> - AJ
> - 10% BuildingDiscount
> - 10% BuildingDiscount Total:
> - Northwestern 10%
> - Northwestern 10% Total:
> - AJ Total:

**Step#2** - ignore the values that contain "10%" (this removes both headings and sub-subtotals

- Enter this formula in Cell K3 and copy to row 31916
- `=iferror(if(search("10%",J3)>0,"",J3),J3)`: searches for "10%" in Column J. Returns all values except those that containing "10%".
- Taking Customer "AJ" as an example, the content at this point includes:

> - AJ
> - AJ Total:

**Step#3 - ignore the values that contain the word "Total"

- Enter this formula in Cell L3 and copy to row 31916.

  - `=iferror(if(search("total",K3)>0,"",K3),K3)`
- Taking Customer "AJ" as an example, the content at this point includes:

> - AJ

---

**Results after Step#3**

[image: Step3 results]

---

You might wonder, "*couldn't this be done in a single formula?*" and/or "*an array formula would be more efficent*". Both those thoughts are true, but we're looking at simple and easy, and a single formula is NOT simple (as shown below); and given that, an array formula is out-of-the-question unless/until an expert can wave a magic wand over the data.

**FWIW - Combining Steps#1, 2 & 3**

- each of the Steps#1, 2 and 3 build on each other. So it *is* possible to create a single formula that combines these steps.
- enter this formula in Cell J3, and copy dow to row #31916.

  - `=iferror(if(search("total",iferror(if(search("10%",if(isdate(A3),"",A3))>0,"",if(isdate(A3),"",A3)),if(isdate(A3),"",A3)))>0,"",iferror(if(search("10%",if(isdate(A3),"",A3))>0,"",if(isdate(A3),"",A3)),if(isdate(A3),"",A3))),iferror(if(search("10%",if(isdate(A3),"",A3))>0,"",if(isdate(A3),"",A3)),if(isdate(A3),"",A3)))`

---

As the image showed, step#3 concludes with mainly empty cells in Column L; the only populated cell is the first instance of the customer name at the start of their transactions - such as "Alec" in this example. However (props to @Rubén) it is possible to populate the blank transaction Cells in Column L. [An arrayformula to find the previous non-empty cell in another column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88400/196152) on Webapps explains how.

**Step#4** - Create a customer name for each transaction row.

- Enter this formula in Cell M3, it will automatically populate the cells to row#31916

  - `=ArrayFormula(vlookup(ROW(3:31916),{IF(LEN(L3:L31916)>0,ROW(3:31916),""),L3:L31916},2))`

**Step#5** - Get the discount amount for each transaction value

- The discount values are already displayed in Column I. They are interspersed with text values, so the formula for tests if this is a total line by testing the value in Column D; only if there is a vale (Product item) does the formula then test of there is a value in column I.

  - Enter this formula in Cell N3, it will automatically populate the cells to row#31916

    - `=ArrayFormula(if(len(D3:D31914)>0,if(ISNUMBER(I3:I31916),I3:I31916,0),""))`

---

**Screenshot after step#5**

[image: Post Step 5 screenshot]

---

**Reporting by Query**

Reporting is done via queries. These can go anywhere, but it is probably more convenient to put it on a separate sheet.

**Step#6.1** - query the results to create report showing total by ALL customers

- `=query(Discounts_analysis!$M$2:$N$31916,"select M, sum(N)  where N is not null group by M label M 'Customer', sum(N) 'Total Discount' ",1)`

**Step#6.2** - query the results to create report showing total by customer **where the customer received a discount**

- `=query(Discounts_analysis!$M$2:$N$31916,"select M, sum(N)  where N >0 group by M label M 'Customer', sum(N) 'Total Discount' ",1)`

**Step#6.3** - query the results to create report showing customers with no discount

```
- `=query(query(Discounts_analysis!$M$2:$N$31916,"select M, sum(N)  where N is not null group by M label M 'Customer', sum(N) 'Total Discount' ",1),"select Col1 where Col2=0")`
```

---

**Queries screenshot**

[image: Queries snapshot]